# Infragistics and DataBinding

Tags: .net, winforms, binding, infragistics

I just need to bind "Enabled" property of `ButtonTool` (Infragistics toolbar button) to a boolean property of my business object.

```
Public Class ToolStripBindableButton
  Inherits Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ButtonTool
  Implements IBindableComponent (?)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
btnButtonTool.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", bizObj, "BoolPropertyInBizObj");
```

**EDIT** 
Ok, since the Enabled property is not exposed directly on ButtonTool, you could expose it yourself by creating your own ButtonTool that inherits the Infragistics one, and then implement property like this:

```
public class MyButtonTool : ButtonTool
{
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get
        {
             return Shared.Enabled;
        }
        set
        {
             OnPropertyChanging("Enabled");
             Shared.Enabled = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("Enabled");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure now what ButtonTool implements (INotifyPropertyChanged/ing) but anyway you get the idea...

Comment: btnButtonTool has no "Enabled" property, nor DataBindings one

Comment: But you said: "I just need to bind "Enabled" property of ButtonTool"... so, if it doesn't exist, what do you expect to bind to? Or maybe your question is what would be equivalent of Enabled property on ButtonTool?

Comment: It has via btnMyButton.Shared.Enabled.